# Javascript await reading text file

Tags: javascript, asynchronous-javascript

This is probably dead simple, but I can't quite figure it out. I simply want to read the contexts of a text file into a variable. What I have is:

```
async function load(path) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(path);
        const text = await response.text();
        return text;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

var source_text = load(source_text_path);
console.log(source_text);
```

To my mind, this should work but only the pending promise is returned and not the text, thought I thought it was awaiting properly.

Comment: You need to await `load` because it is asynchronous (or chain it with a `then`)

Comment: I was also thinking this, but awaiting load when I create source_text gives this console error: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules.

Comment: So you need to do just that - put it in an async function. If your intent is to get the value from a synchronous call even though the operation is asynchronous, then I'm afraid you need to rethink your approach, because information can't time-travel back into the synchronous call result when it arrives only later on. If this is for initialization: A common aporoach is to have these things in asynchronous `init` functions which some (also async) main function will call (and await) on startup. The synchronous top-level code then does `main().catch(e => { console.error(e); process.exit(1) })`

Comment: Alternatively, you could change your project to use ES modules, because then (as the error suggested as well) you _can_ use `await` in top-level code (because importing a module is in itself an asynchronous operation, unlike `require`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the `load` method.

```
var source_text = await load(source_text_path);
```

OR

```
load(source_text_path).then(e => console.log(e))
```

Comment: I was also thinking this, but awaiting the call to load() when I create source_text gives this console error: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules.

Answer (score 1):

The function is indeed awaiting as it should, but since it's `async`, it will always result in a `Promise<things>` when you `return thing`.

Which means you should either `await` it elsewhere:

```
var source_text = await load(source_text_path);
```

or `then` it:

```
load(source_text_path).then((source_text) => {
  console.log(source_text);
})
```